# There something may be wrong with my calculation for tcp checksum,or simple pointer handling&writing to it at certain offset,is it checksum or writing

Tags: c, math, tcp, byte, bit

This is what I am doing before calling my `csum` function for getting checksum. At end I call csum function. But the way it's done is not giving me correct values printing for example I printed checksum before calculating checksum and assigning 0 then printf after I calculated checksum of received packet then printf again.

I do not think there is anything strangely wrong with code and that can be added to my tcp_chksum function but it's still not quite printing correct values.

So I'd like to know am I missing anything obvious or wrongly done?

The csum is calculating correct ip checksum for of received packets and this is double checked.

This is my tcp_chksum and csum function:

```
uint16_t tcp_chksum(struct iphdr *snd_iph, struct tcphdr *snd_tcph)
{
    struct psuedo_header psh;

    psh.src_addr = snd_iph->saddr;
    psh.dst_addr = snd_iph->daddr;
    psh.rsvd = 0;
    psh.proto = IPPROTO_TCP;
    psh.len_tcp = htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr)); /* No options, and no data */

    int pseudogram_size = sizeof(struct tcphdr) + sizeof(struct psuedo_header);
    char *pseudogram = malloc(pseudogram_size);

    memcpy(pseudogram, (char *)&psh, sizeof(struct psuedo_header));
    memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct psuedo_header), snd_tcph, sizeof(struct tcphdr));

    return(htons(csum(pseudogram, pseudogram_size)));
    //return (htons(csum(snd_tcph, sizeof(struct my_tcph)) + csum(&psh, sizeof(struct psuedo_header))));
}
```

And this is csum function:

```
uint16_t csum(const void *data, const int length)
{
    /*  Checksum Algorithm (http://www.microhowto.info/howto/calculate_an_internet_protocol_checksum_in_c.html)
    1. Set the sum to 0,
    2. Pad the data to an even number of bytes,
    3. Reinterpret the data as a sequence of 16-bit unsigned integers that are
        in network byte order,
    4. Calculate the sum of the integers, subtracting 0xffff whenever
        the sum => 0x10000, and
    5. Calculate the bitwise complement of the sum and set it as the checksum.
    */
    //printf("[[[[[[[[%d]]]]]]]]\n",length);
    uint16_t *accumalator = (uint16_t *)data;
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    /* Take care of the first 16-bit even blocks */
    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i) {
        sum += *(accumalator+i);
        if (sum >= 0x10000) {
            sum -= 0xffff;
        }
    }

    /* Handle the ending partial block */
    if (length % 2 != 0) {
        accumalator = accumalator+ length/2; /* Point accumalator to the end block */
        uint16_t end_block = 0;
        memcpy(&end_block, accumalator, sizeof(length));
        sum += ntohs(end_block);
        if (sum >= 0x10000) {
            sum -= 0xffff;
        }
    }
  //  printf("%d == sum\n",htons(~sum));
    /* Return the one's complement of the checksum in network byte order */
    return htons(~sum);
}
```

and I am calling tcp_chksum function like this

```
   tcph->check=tcp_chksum(iph,tcph);
```

iph and tcph are pointers point to array the used in read function of type iphdr and tcphdr, and to calculate ip checksum for received packet before my this question function calls I did `iph->check = csum(iph, sizeof(*iph))`.

One difference I see is in my only ip checksum calculation I am passing second parameter as `sizeof(*pointer_of type iphdr)` and in my tcp checksum I am passing `sizeof(struct tcphdr)` as second parameter.

Comment: problem may be I need to calculation csum for psudoheader and tcph then do byte order conversion I

Comment: also wireshark is showing my packets as malformed does it also mean my checksum calculation incorrect

Comment: I think I will fix it if I remove two calls to htons.

Comment: also, using `malloc` and then non freeing the memory is a mistake (memory leak). you need to call `free` on your pseudoheader before returning your checksum.

Comment: `also, using malloc and then non freeing the memory is a mistake (memory leak). you need to call free on your pseudoheader before returning your checksum.` is it possible it can also give me wrong checksum because of this?

Comment: no, only memory leak